# Minimum time passed for stationary observer at destination in relativistic physics

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, time-dilation, thought-experiment, optimization

While my friend and I were discussing about relativistic physics, we came up with the following question.

> Suppose a person $P$ wanted to travel from point $A$ to point $B$ in one-dimensional space. There is a stationary observer at point $B$, waiting for $P$ to arrive. At what constant speed should $P$ travel to minimize the amount of time the observer perceives that they are waiting?

The intuition is if $P$ travels faster, the observer generally has to wait for less time, but at a certain point, the effects of time dilation might make going faster counterproductive.

Our attempt was as follows.

Let $v$ be the desired speed, and let $d$ be the distance from point $A$ to point $B$. Let $T$ be the time passed for the observer, and note that $\frac{d}{v}$ is the time passed for $P$. We have
\begin{align*}
T &= \frac{d}{v\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}} \\
\frac{d}{dv}T &= \frac{d(2v^2 - c^2)}{c^2v^2\left(1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}.
\end{align*}
Setting the numerator equal to $0$,
\begin{align*}
d(2v^2 - c^2) &= 0 \\
v &= \frac{c}{\sqrt{2}}. \\
\end{align*}
Is this solution valid? I searched online but could not find sources that referred to $\frac{c}{\sqrt{2}}$ as the speed that achieves the minimum time passed as perceived by the observer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may not have understood your question correctly, but if I did, then you're muddling up reference frames.

First: Who is "they"?

> the observer perceives that **they** are waiting?

If "they" is the observer, then all what counts is the velocity of P: The faster P travels, the quicker P will arrive, the less the observer has to wait. So P would need to travel with the maximum velocity: The speed of light. Time Dilation is irrelevant, as P's proper time is not considered (the reference frame is the one of the observer, and she asks for her own waiting time). So the observer waits $T=\frac{d}{c}$.

If "they" is P, then the result is the same, but the waiting time even less: P's proper time slows down, the more, the faster P travels. At light speed, no time will pass for P anymore, P won't have to wait at all: $T=0$. At light speed the distance between A and B becomes (i.e. as seen by P) zero (length contraction).

Comment: Thanks for the response. The intended interpretation was the first one. Is there any physical scenario that can be described by the equation written in the post, now that I see the one we have come up with does not fit? (In other words, is there any significance of $\frac{c}{\sqrt{2}}$?)

Comment: There may be, but it would be coincidental, I guess, as your derivation does not fit any physical situation.